# Commerce Kickstart Facet Displays Item Count Even With Option Disabled

Tags: 7, commerce, search

I'm using Kickstart2.

I imported a new set of Categories and Collections using a Taxonomy Feed Importer. Seemed to work OK but now, the facet display -always- shows the item count for -all- search vocabularies, even though I have that option disabled in each search field eg.

admin/config/search/facetapi/search_api%2540product_display/block/field_category/edit

I can't see how the Feed Import would cause this so maybe that's a red herring, but regardless, this worked properly -before- my import and now I can't turn this item count off.

Any idea how to get rid of these?

> [image: Facets displaying item count]

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the settings under vocabulary, go to `admin/structure/taxonomy/product_category/edit` and then uncheck the **Display number of items** that's it, it will not show you the count anymore.

> [image]

Comment: I disabled that and it still displays. I think I figured it out. It's hard-coded in the current commerce kickstart facetapi for widget-links. Will post answer later.